# Custom exit and minimize in JavaFX unexpected problems

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, javafx, operating-system

So I have two ways of exiting my applications, with the buttons I created and with the keybindings I created.

The problems I am having are with minimize. For the button, I click it on initial launch and it doesnt work. The second time I click it, it will then work. Here is the code for the button.

```
@FXML
public void minimizeClick() {
    minimizeButton.setOnAction(e ->
            ( (Stage) ( (Button) e.getSource() ).getScene().getWindow() ).setIconified(true)
    );
}
```

Now for the keybindings, it will work the first time when I press CMD+M on Mac OS. When I bring up the application again in the same session, it will stutter. So I then have to use the key-bind combination twice for it to execute the action. Here is the code:

```
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.COMMAND) {
            detW = true;
            detM = true;
        }
        if(detW && e.getCode() == KeyCode.W) {
            System.exit(0);
            detW = false;
        }
        else if(detM && e.getCode() == KeyCode.M) {
            primaryStage.setIconified(true);
            detM = false;
        }
    });
```

The 3rd condition handles the minimizing. The method handles exiting program as well but obviously I can only exit the program once, so far at least. In the future I will have termination be mapped to CMD+Q instead of CMD+W.

Why is this not working?

Comment: what java version are you using? Or more exactly what which javafx version?

Comment: I believe javafx 8

Comment: Can you please try to update your jdk at least to 8.144 . It was a time when setIconified(true) was freezing my application as well. Can you please update your java, and give it a try?

Comment: Why is the method annotated `@FXML`? Is it registered as a handler method in an FXML file? If so, why is it registering another handler?

Comment: For the key handlers, you should use `KeyEvent.isShortcutDown()` etc instead of trying to track the command key yourself.

Comment: It is marked @FXML because the button is from an fxml file and it is in a separate controller class from the main class.

Comment: @user2805346 I actually have 8.144

Comment: @compute But then the method is the handler method for the button, no?  So when the button is pressed, `minimizeClick()` is executed, when then changes the button's handler to the new handler. So the next time you click it, the new handler, which minimizes the window is executed. In other words, this is exactly the expected behavior for the code you have used.

Comment: Can you provide a demonstration at least? You are not making any sense to me.

Comment: I don't know what doesn't make sense. If you have `onAction="#minimizeClick"` in the definition of your button in FXML, it means "when the user presses the button, execute the `minimizeClick` method". So your `minimizeClick` method should minimize the window (not register a different action handler).

Comment: I have done this, and it works, it just doesn't work twice. You are not making any sense. Did you read my post?

Comment: You have done what? Did you change your `minimizeClick` method so that it just minimizes the window, instead of what you have currently in your question. (You understand that `minimizeButton.setOnAction(...)` doesn't minimize a window, right?) If so, please post the new version of your method.

Comment: @compute Added an answer (now I am back at my computer). Not sure what is in there that I didn't already explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post your FXML file, but I'm going to assume you have something like

```xml
<Button text="..." fx:id="minimizeButton" onAction="#minimizeClick" />
```

in it.

Buttons have a property called `onAction`, of type `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`. If the button is clicked (or otherwise fired, e.g. via the keyboard), then if `onAction` is not null, it is executed.

The `onAction="#minimizeClick"` sets the `onAction` property to an `EventHandler` which invokes the `minimizeClick()` method defined in the controller.

So you can think of all this as *"when the button is clicked, `minimizeClick()` is invoked in the controller"*.

Your `minimizeClick()` method is this:

```
@FXML
public void minimizeClick() {
    minimizeButton.setOnAction(e ->
            ( (Stage) ( (Button) e.getSource() ).getScene().getWindow() ).setIconified(true)
    );
}
```

What this method does, is set the button's `onAction` property to a new handler; i.e. it replaces the current `onAction` handler with a new handler (which minimizes the window).

So the first time the button is clicked, `minimizeClick()` is invoked. That replaces the current `onAction` handler (invoke `minimizeClick()`) with a new handler.

The second (and any subsequent) time the button is clicked, the newly-installed `onAction` handler is invoked, which minimizes the window.

Consequently the behavior you actually see is that nothing happens on the first button click, but on the second button click the window is minimized.

If you were not using FXML (Java only), then your code would be equivalent to

```
minimizeButton.setOnAction(e1 -> {
    minimizeButton.setOnAction(e2 -> {
        ((Stage)((Button)e2.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()).setIconified(true);
    });
});
```

Obviously, you just want a simple handler that minimizes the button, i.e. you want the `minimizeClick()` method to minimize the window. So you need

```
@FXML
public void minimizeClick() {
    ( (Stage) ( (Button) e.getSource() ).getScene().getWindow() ).setIconified(true);
}
```

---

I don't understand what you mean by "when I bring up the application again it will stutter", but it sounds like that is unrelated to the code you posted. For your key event handlers, you should use `KeyEvent.isShortcutDown()` etc to see if the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key is pressed when the key of interest is pressed, instead of trying to keep track of it yourself. I.e. try

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.W && e.isShortcutDown()) {
        System.exit(0);
        // Aside: you should really use Platform.exit() instead of System.exit(0)
        // as it will gracefully shutdown the FX toolkit and ensure your
        // Application's stop() method is called, etc.
    } else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.M && e.isShortcutDown()) {
        primaryStage.setIconified(true);
    }
});
```

Note that the default (native OS) behavior of <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> on a Mac is to minimize the window, so this may be confounding the behavior you observe. (I.e. I think on a Mac this behavior may occur without any of these key handlers.)

Comment: This makes sense to me now. I had suspected I was essentially calling the same thing twice but had overlooked the idea that I can get elements that are constructed in the fxml

Comment: @compute Being able to access the FXML elements in the controller has nothing at all to do with the mistake you were making. I removed that part as it seems to be confusing you (still).

Comment: Yes because before I would remove that it would have e as an undeclared variable and I wouldn't know what to substitute for that. But now I realize instead of casting to a button I could call the actual button that is in the FXML file.